# How to fill many polygons with the same color scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a Finite Element Finite (FEM), and I am having problems to show the results as intended.

I am able to do a colourfill with the values I want with just one polygon (triangle, quadrilateral), but the problem is when I do the same with another one, the color plot resets itself, and it has different values, meaning that the same tension I get in one node, has a different color from one side to another.

```
tri1 = np.array([[0.25,0.1],[1,2],[0.5,2]])
val1 = np.array([1,3,2])
tri2 = np.array([[0.5,2],[1,2],[1.2,3.75]])
val2 = np.array([2,3,6])

mat1 = np.c_[tri1,val1]
mat2 = np.c_[tri2,val2]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def colourfill(mat_global,ax, label = None):
    import matplotlib.tri as tri
    triangulacion = tri.Triangulation(mat_global[:,0],mat_global[:,1])
    
    pc = ax.tripcolor(triangulacion, mat_global[:,2], cmap='viridis', shading='gouraud')
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(pc)
    cbar.set_label(label)


colourfill(mat1,ax,'Testing')
colourfill(mat2,ax)
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

I am expecting, first, to have the same scale colors and also a good colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify the `vmin` and `vmax` inside the `tripcolor` function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tri1 = np.array([[0.25,0.1],[1,2],[0.5,2]])
val1 = np.array([1,3,2])
tri2 = np.array([[0.5,2],[1,2],[1.2,3.75]])
val2 = np.array([2,3,6])

mat1 = np.c_[tri1,val1]
mat2 = np.c_[tri2,val2]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def colourfill(mat_global,ax, label = None):
    import matplotlib.tri as tri
    triangulacion = tri.Triangulation(mat_global[:,0],mat_global[:,1])
    
    pc = ax.tripcolor(triangulacion, mat_global[:,2], cmap='viridis', shading='gouraud', vmin=0, vmax=3)
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(pc)
    cbar.set_label(label)
    return 

colourfill(mat1,ax,'Testing')
colourfill(mat2,ax)
plt.show()
```

This returns:

[image]

**EDIT:** instead of hardcoding `vmin` and `vmax` like I did in the example above, you may derive them from the min and max values in the `mat1[:,2]` and `mat2[:,2]` matrices, *e.g.*:

```
vmin = np.min([mat1[:,2],mat1[:,2]])
```